# Can I bind a key to enable a certain power?

Tags: dishonored

Selecting Dark Vision on the hotbar everytime I want to enable/disable it is pretty annoying. Is it possible to bind a key to toggle this power, e.g. by editing one of the ini file?

Comment: Might be able to do something with 'm_PCBindings' in the ini file. I need to search more in the intarnet

Comment: A bit more info on using m_PCbindings http://www.gamefront.com/how-to-improve-dishonored-with-ini-file-tweaks/

Comment: [This post](http://www.witchboy.net/2012/10/09/dishonored-pro-tips/) says you can, but doesn't say how -- maybe pressing the number key while the desired power is selected, before closing the radial menu (that's similar to how it works on the 360).

Comment: I think those shortcuts just *select* the weapon/power instead of activating them without changing the active one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not possible, as the PC version seems to be a simple port of the console version. On a console you don't really have that much buttons you can rebind, thus the hotbar and radial menu. This is an issue that most game-studios/publishers seem to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

You can map any skills from the Skill Wheel to the number keys, just open the Wheel (using Middle Mouse Button), select a skill and press the number key you want it have assigned to.

So in short:

1. Press middle mouse button
2. Select skill
3. Press [1-9]

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. I'm looking for a way to bind a key to *use* the skill right now. There is e.g. no point in selecting Dark Vision - I'd like to **toggle** that skill on/off with a keypress while keeping something useful selected.

Comment: Oops, misunderstood you there. Sorry.

Comment: While I think this does not really answer the question, I also think this is as close to a solution as you can get without modding the game.

Answer (score 1):

Since Dishonored is an Unreal 3 engine based game, you can try setting up an alias which will chain two commands: switch to a particular skill (or at least press a specific number key), attack.

See the ue3 docs: ("key bind chaining" & "key bind aliasing")

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/KeyBinds.html

You can probably derive the commands for left-hand/right-hand attack and skill selection from the INI file(s). At the very least you'd be able to automate the 1-9 selection and attack, and then fill the slots manually.